# 引数のアノテーションで、UnionとOptionalを併用する方法

Tags: python, python3, mypy

以下のソースコードにおいて、

```
def func( key:Union[int,list] = None):
    ...
```

keyという引数は、Optionalでありながら、Unionでint、listにもなりうるものです。

Linter(Mypy)でエラーとして検出されてしまいます。

どのような記述方法が正解なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

手元の環境(mypy 1.3.0)で、`None`を許容するように書き換える方法でも警告がなくなりました。

```
def func(key:Union[int,list] = None): # 修正前
def func(key:Union[int,list,None] = None): # 修正後
```

**修正前のmypy実行結果**

```
hoge.py:3: error: Incompatible default for argument "key" (default has type "None", argument has type "Union[int, List[Any]]")  [assignment]
hoge.py:3: note: PEP 484 prohibits implicit Optional. Accordingly, mypy has changed its default to no_implicit_optional=True
hoge.py:3: note: Use https://github.com/hauntsaninja/no_implicit_optional to automatically upgrade your codebase
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

**修正後のmypy実行結果**

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) をそのまま使って構いません。

```py
from typing import Union, Optional

Optional[Union[int, list]]
```

なお、以下のように書き換え可能ですので、最短の型表記は `int | list | None` だと思います。既に有る payaneco さんの回答とも意味的に同じです。

```py
# 全て意味的に同じ型
print(
    Optional[Union[int, list]] ==
    Union[Union[int, list], None] ==
    (int | list) | None ==
    int | list | None
)
# => True
```

Answer (score 0):

型エイリアスを使えばよいことがわかりました。

```
aliasKey = Union[int,list]
def func( key:Optinal[aliasKey ] = None):
    ...
```